# A new type for all a (normal value) and nothing in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to

1. create a new type and value that indicates `none` like `Nothing` of `Maybe`.
2. create a new union type for all `a` (normal value) and `none`
3. create a function that accepts the new union type, then if the argument is the `none` does nothing.

Without using `Maybe`, how can I do this in Haskell?

In Typescript

```
  const none = { undefined };
  type None = typeof none;
  type Option<T> = None | T;
 
  type f = <T>(a:Option<T>) => any; 
  const f:f = a =>
    a === none
      ? undefined
      : console.log(a);
```

How to do this in Haskell? and just in case, please note here I'm not asking how to use `Maybe` Monad. Thanks.

Comment: Haskell doesn't have union types. It has tagged unions. And the tagged union of a type `a` with a "nothing" value is `Maybe a`. You can write the data declaration yourself (`data MyMaybe a = MyNothing | MyJust a`), but it's still the same idea.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo
 Thanks but your comment is exactly what I don't want as I stated in my Question. So the answer is "impossible" if I'm correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want the exact equivalent of Typescript's `null | T`, then that's not possible in Haskell (even with copious GHC extensions, I can't think of a way to define that exact type). It's just not how the language is built.

Comment: Thanks I still want to try in some way.

Comment: You can want to try, but it's not possible to do anything better than the first comment.

Comment: @LouisWasserman See the answer and you seem to be too haste to the conclusion limiting possibilities.

Comment: @sailsky: I've reviewed the answer, and I'm comfortable with my comment.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You technically denied someone's trial and possibility, and it turned out it's actually possible. Do you really think it's an adequate and productive manner?

Comment: @sailsky The answer below does **not** say it's possible (and I wrote it). My answer to your follow up question does kinda show it's possible, but not in any way that you can pleasantly use. I fully agree with Louis' position that it's not possible do anything *better* than `Maybe`. I really think ultimately you will be better served (and more productive) if you can stop pre-judging how you think problems *should* be solved based on your experience in other languages and ask how to do that, and instead learn/ask how to use Haskell's tools to solve your problems. I promise you it is rewarding!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an actual programming problem you're trying to solve which requires you to represent the concept of "either a value of type T or nothing", then Haskell's answer to that is to use `Maybe T`.

Whatever the goal of your code, if in Typescript you would use your `Option` to meat that goal, in Haskell you can use `Maybe` to meet that goal. The code will be a little different, but that's unsurprising because they are different languages.

But if you are trying to directly use the concepts involved in your `Option` from Typescript, in Haskell, to implement a type that is exactly the same for its own sake (rather than as a tool to solve a problem), then you're out of luck. Haskell does not **have** the concept of an (undiscriminated) union type, nor the means to easily simulate one<sup>1</sup>.

You could sort-of try with `Typeable`:

```
import Data.Typeable (Typeable, cast)

data None = None

f :: (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> IO ()
f x = case (cast x :: Maybe None)
        of Just None -> pure ()
           Nothing -> print x
```

When we've got a `Typeable` constraint in play we can actually check if a value is of a certain type (and if so get a reference to it where the reference has the right type, so we can use it as that type). But this forces us to go via `Maybe` anyway, because `cast` needs a way to represent the value of a cast that didn't succeed!

It's also warty because now an actual argument of our `None` type can't be represented at all, whereas the `Maybe` option can represent `Just Nothing` just fine. It's true that you don't *often* need this "nested failure-or-absence" capability (though by no means never; think of a query that might not return a result: if you need to distinguish between the failure to run the query vs the query returning no result, that's quite naturally `Maybe (Maybe Result)`). But I prefer my facilities that handle any type to handle **any** type, with uniformity. You can't get caught out by odd corner cases if there aren't any corner cases, by design.

And you can't use `Typeable` more generally to actually declare a type that could be the union of two specific types; you have to accept a type variable `a` with a `Typeable` constraint, which means people can pass you **any** type, not just the two you were trying to put into a union. Since you can only write a finite number of `cast`s, `Typeable` fundamentally can only be used to handle a set of particular types specially, or a code path for anything else (which might be to error out).

As a more general point, you need to avoid over-using `Typeable` in order to write code that gains all the benefits of Haskell's type system. Lots of Haskell code makes use of properties that arise from what you *can't* do with a polymorphic type, because you don't know which concrete type it is. All of those go out the window when `Typeable` is in play. For a very simple example, there's the classic argument that there's only one function of type `a -> a` (that doesn't bottom out); with no way to know what the type `a` is, the function's implementation can't create one out of nothing, so it can only return it unmodified. But a function types `Typeable a => a -> a` could have any number of oddball rules encoded like "if the argument is an `Integer`, add one to it". No matter what is hiding in the implementation it won't be reflected in the type beyond the `Typeable` constraint, so you have to be familiar with the particulars of the implementation to work with this function, and the compiler won't spot if you make a mistake. A clear example of this effect is that in my attempt to write `f` above, we end up with the type `f :: Typeable a => a -> IO ()`; there is *zero* indication of what types it is expecting to work with (that it wants to handle "either `None` or anything else").

As a totally different track, you can do this of course:

```
data None = None
data Option a = Some a | None' None
```

Now you've "created a new type to represent nothing" and "create a new union type for all `a` (normal value) and none". But Haskell's ADTs are **discrimated** unions, meaning there will always be a constructor tag (both at runtime and in your source code) on each variant in the union.

So there's really no point in having the separate `None` type, since once you've seen the `None'` tag in an `Option a` value you already know everything there is to know about the value; looking inside the `None` value to see that it is `None` tells you nothing<sup>2</sup>. So you might as well just use:

```
data Option a = Some a | None
```

Which is exactly the same as the built in `Maybe`, differing only in the names chosen.

Similarly you can obviously write a function with a case to handle when an `Option` is `None`, and a case to handle when there is something there (either of which can "do nothing", if you're returning a type where "doing something" makes any sense, i.e. some sort of action, like `IO` or `State`).

```
f :: Show a => Option a -> IO a
f None = pure ()
f (Some a) = print a
```

The code is *slightly* different, even ignoring for trivial syntax and naming issues; we had to reference the `Some` constructor and call `print` on the value *inside* it, rather than printing the argument to `f` directly<sup>3</sup>. And Haskell uses a typeclass divide types into ones that can meaningfully be printed and ones that can't, and only allow you to call `print` on the former. But it's so close that I have no reservations saying "this is the equivalent Haskell to the Typescript you wrote".

And given that `Maybe` already exists you might as well use it. (Similarly, should you ever need it the built in type `()` is - apart from the name - identical to `data None = None`.) But again: that is what you do if you are trying to solve a problem that you would use `Option` for in Typescript; if instead your goal is to implement something *exactly the same as `Option`*, then you simply can't with the tools Haskell gives you.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can *probably* hack something truly horrible together using unsafe features (like `unsafeCoerce`ing to and from `Any`). I do not know exactly how to go about making that usable and reliable, and doing so is an utter waste of time for any *practical* purpose; you would never use such code in a real program, it would just be an interesting exercise in how far you can hack the language implementation. So I'm not going to write an answer that addresses that angle.

---

<sup>2</sup> Well, technically it sells you that the computation that produced it terminated; it could have been bottom. But you can't do anything with that information since it's impossible to *test* whether it was bottom; if it is you'll just error out (or not terminate) as well.

---

<sup>3</sup> Printing the whole argument to `f` would have also worked, it would have just printed e.g. `Some "value"`, which I assume is not what you meant.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Ben.. In mathematical sense, my demand is simply setA + setB. I'm rather surprised Haskell can't do this. I'm afraid to say many lines you wrote is simply a justification of impossible, and I really think it should be possible.

Comment: I know there is algebraic data type, like `A | B | C`, but this incapability suggests Haskell doesn't have a way to express the whole set of the value like Typescript, unfortunately.

Comment: "meet the goal" philosophy you try to teach here is actually nothing to do with the mathematical incapability, and IMO, a language should not justify that, same goes to the language users, I wish.

Comment: I observe Maybe-monad is very problematic to use especially to combine with IO `do` thread, and you say "trivial" thing, but actually it's not and that's why people needs Monad transformers etc. I think in many cases Maybe or in a more general word Option-monad should be an anti-pattern if one just needs a empty value like my case.

Comment: To have `setU = setT + setN` and  to have `setMaybe = set(setT) + setN`  are different and the latter produces much more complexity and I don't think that should be the proper "answer".

Comment: @sailsky Haskell's ADTs are built to model categorical products and coproducts. That's perfectly "mathematical", it's just apparently not the mathematical system you wanted. Haskell is also a programming language, not a mathematical modelling system (which TypeScript is even further from!), so making it possible for programmers to achieve their goals is a more important consideration than directly supporting every different mathematical concept; I don't know why you think a programming language shouldn't be designed with "'meet the goal' philosophy".

Comment: @sailsky Without the tags in the tagged unions, how would you do pattern matching? How would you know which alternative resides within a type? Would you fall back to runtime type checking? That could be significantly more costly than simply having a tag!

Comment: @sailaky I also think "true mathematical union" types would be different from typescript unions. If we're considering types as sets, a union type should logically support only the operations that could be done on **all** of the constituent types (which would make `A` indistinguishable from `A | A`, as you would expect from set-union). Being able to tell "which side" of the union it came from is the key feature of coproducts rather than set-union. Typescript unions appear to just mandate that you only union disjoint types, which makes them very similar in capability to discriminated unions.

Comment: @sailsky And if we're supporting union types for the sake of not having "mathematical incapacities", why aren't you demanding that Haskell (and typescript) has *intersection* types too? Once you've got unions, intersections that are non-empty are possible; intersection types should logically support any operation defined on any of the constituent types (since every value is a member of all of them). Or indeed type operations based on any other set operation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments, I will study .

Comment: In fact, since I did not know about `Typeable`, your explanation helps a lot. Appreciated.

Comment: @sailsky Glad to hear it! Though I feel it's worth stressing: if you're truly interested in mathematical reasoning in your type system, `Typeable` is exactly what you *don't* want. It's extremely handy for a few things, but it does invalidate most of the properties/theorems you could otherwise deduce from types. So using `Typeable` a lot makes your types "less mathematical".

Comment: @Ben I'm sorry for my late reply, I didn't recognize your comments. In fact after this QA(I really appreciated again), I tried Maybe approach a couple of times, but I thought the complication that deliver to code is far from justified at least for my purpose, and decided to use `Typeable` extention because there is nothing else I can do as you kindly elaborated in your answer here.

Comment: Actually, I even considered to use Idris that employs dependent types, and installed tweaked, but for several reasons I eventually be back to Haskell with Typeable which I'm so sorry to hear it breaks the mathematical integrity, but good to hear you stressed out!