# Data.Typeable cast and Maybe pattern match behavior in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Based on this QA;

[A new type for all a (normal value) and nothing in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189850/a-new-type-for-all-a-normal-value-and-nothing-in-haskell)

Here's the first working code:

```
import Data.Typeable (Typeable, cast)

data None = None

none :: None
none = None

f :: Typeable a => a -> a
f = \x ->
  case (cast x :: Maybe None) of
    Just None -> undefined
    Nothing -> x

test :: IO ()
test = do
  print $ f (5 :: Int)  --5
  pure $ f none
  print "done"
```

This code works as I intended.

Now, I want to make this optionMap and here is the non-working code with an error:

```
import Data.Typeable (Typeable, cast)

data None = None

none :: None
none = None

optionMap :: Typeable a => (a -> b) -> a -> b
optionMap = \f -> \x ->
  case (cast x :: Maybe None) of
    Just None -> undefined
    Nothing -> f x

test :: IO ()
test = do
  print $ optionMap (\a -> a + 1) (5 :: Int) -- 6
  pure $ optionMap (\a -> a + 1) none
  -- No instance for (Num None) arising from a use of ‘+’
  print "done"
```

Surely, I understand the meaning of the error, however, I expect it pattern-matched as `Just None` as the first working example, then the value should be `undefined`.

Is it possible to fix?

Comment: In the line that is failing: what type do you expect `a` to have in the lambda?

Answer (score 6):

Well, I specifically said in my answer to your other question that `Typeable` *isn't* a good tool to address this goal. But sure, let's see if we can fix it.

For starters, this is pretty silly:

```
optionMap :: Typeable a => (a -> b) -> a -> b
optionMap = \f -> \x ->
  case (cast x :: Maybe None) of
    Just None -> undefined
    Nothing -> f x
```

If the function `f` can handle arguments of type `a`, and we have an `x` of type `a`, there's no need to check for `None` at all; `f x` is valid. If you really want `optionMap`, you don't want it to have this type.

To see why, let's look at the way you were calling it. With `optionMap (\a -> a + 1) none` you need all these types to unify:

```
(\a -> a + 1) :: Num t =>   t -> t
none ::                                None
optionMap :: Typeable a => (a -> b) -> a    -> b
```

I've lined them up (and use globally unique names for type variables) to make it clear what type inference is going to happen. We're going to decide that `a ~ t`, and `b ~ t`, but also that `a ~ None`. If any of these facts were not true, we would have a type error. So GHC assumes they are all true, but that gives us as a combined type of `optionMap`:

```
optionMap :: (Typeable None, Num None) => (None -> None) -> None -> None
```

Not very helpful! The whole point of `None` was that the function *wouldn't* be applied if it was `None`, so we don't want any of the constraints from the function to end up as constraints on the `a` when we pass a `None` in that position. The only way we can achieve that is by having the type of the function parameter's parameter be a **different** type variable from the second parameter of `optionMap`. So:

```
optionMap :: (Typeable a, Typeable a') => (a' -> b) -> a -> b
```

But now `optionMap` accepts *any* type `a`, not just the `a'` values that can be passed to its function parameter. What we need is to then use `cast` the other way around from the way you used it; check if it's safe to pass `x` to `f` and handle that specially (by returning `f x`), and put our do-nothing case in the branch where the `cast` *failed*. Something like:

```
optionMap :: forall a a' b. (Typeable a, Typeable a') => (a' -> b) -> a -> b
optionMap f x =
  case (cast x :: Maybe a') of
    Just x' -> f x'
    Nothing -> undefined
```

Note that doing that requires the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension (otherwise in the `cast x :: Maybe a'` the `a'` is a new local type variable, not a reference to the `a'` from `optionMap`'s signature), and requires we explicitly introduce the type variables with `forall` (that's how you declare a larger-scope type variable that can be referenced from more than one signature, with `ScopedTypeVariables`).

Lets try it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable

data None = None
none = None

optionMap :: forall a' a b. (Typeable a, Typeable a') => (a' -> b) -> a -> b
optionMap f x =
  case (cast x :: Maybe a') of
    Just x' -> f x'
    Nothing -> undefined


main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ optionMap (\a -> a + 1) (5 :: Int)
  pure $ optionMap (\a -> a + 1) none
  print "done"
```

Unfortunately we get a bunch of messages like:

```
foo.hs:17:3: warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
```

With the `Typeable` constraints, GHC is no longer willing to default the ambiguous types to `Integer`. Plus we've disconnected the type of the function parameter and the other paramter to `optionMap`, so the explicit annotation in `(5 :: Int)` tells us nothing about the type of the function (which we need to know in order for `cast` to tell us whether `5 :: Int` is the same type!), so it' probably *good* that GHC won't default types of the functions or it would have picked `Integer -> Integer`, which *doesn't* match. I frequently try to use `Bool` or `Char` in these small test programs rather than numbers, for exactly this reason; `Num` and defaulting just make everything a little more complicated. But ets try that again with more types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable

data None = None
none = None

optionMap :: forall a' a b. (Typeable a, Typeable a') => (a' -> b) -> a -> b
optionMap f x =
  case (cast x :: Maybe a') of
    Just x' -> f x'
    Nothing -> undefined


main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) (5 :: Int)
  pure $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) none
  print "done"
```

Great it compiles, and if we run it:

```
❯ runhaskell foo.hs
6
"done"
```

But there's a problem:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) (5 :: Int)
  pure $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) 'a'
  pure $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) True
  pure $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) (5 :: Integer)
  pure $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) (print False)
  print "done"
```

All of these *also* happily take the non-equal types path. We haven't written `optionMap` so that it accepts either `None` or the type that matches the function's argument, we've made it accept **any type at all**, and applies the function if the types happen to match. Which means the type checker is *completely* unable to detect any mistakes we make. Any mistake where we *intended* the types to match but we messed up will be silently ignored.

We can try explicitly handling `None`:

```
optionMap :: forall a' a b. (Typeable a, Typeable a') => (a' -> b) -> a -> b
optionMap f x =
  case (cast x :: Maybe a') of
    Just x' -> f x'
    Nothing ->
      case (cast x :: Maybe None) of
        Just None -> undefined
        Nothing -> error "what do we put here?"
```

But no matter how many layers deep of `cast` and `case` we go, we're going to be left with that final "it could be absolutely anything else" case; we don't end up with a clean `optionMap` that accepts the correct type to apply the function or `None`, and nothing else.

What we need is a way to make a type for that second parameter that isn't just a universal `a`, but rather is a specific type for `None or a'`. That's **exactly** what you asked the other question about, and is exactly what I said `Typeable` wouldn't really help you do.

Haskell of course has an extremely uncomplicated and easy way of representing the choice between two types: discriminated unions, AKA algebraic data types with multiple constructors. That's exactly what you have already rejected because "the complication that deliver to code is far from justified at least for my purpose".

---

Before I address how you can *actually* address your need, I need to come back to another problem with your attempt: why are you using `undefined`? `undefined` does **not** "do nothing"; it isn't a neutral value can use when you haven't got what you need, as `null` is often used in other programming languages. When Haskell hits a place you've written `undefined` it terminates the program with an error message. I suspect you know that, because you didn't write `print` in the line of your test program that was supposed to handle the `none` example of using `optionMap`, you wrote `pure`.

`pure` of course wraps up the result in an `IO Int`, but because we do anything with it nothing actually happens. We'd get exactly the same result from:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) (5 :: Int)
  pure $ error "didn't run"
  print "done"
```

So it's a pretty pointless test of `optionMap`. What actually happens if we try to use it, changing the `pure` to a `print`:

```
❯ runhaskell foo.hs
6
foo.hs: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at foo.hs:12:16 in main:Main
```

Using `optionMap _ none` isn't a type error, but if it ever actually gets evaluated it terminates the program with an error. If we were happy with that we could skip this whole attempt and just use:

```
print $ (\a -> a + 1) 5
print $ (\a -> a + 1) undefined
```

Because `undefined` is a member of every type (along with infinite loops, and `error "whatever"`, and a whole host of other ways of writing the bottom value), we can *already* just pass a "wrong" value when we haven't got a real one, if we're happy with this "error out at runtime" behaviour (which I personally am not).

So **even if** we could put in even more work and somehow get a type for `optionMap` that works the way you want, it **still** doesn't give you the ability to feed in a `none` to a computation expecting some other type and have the program ignore it. To do *that* you'd need to also have some way of "mapping" `print` across your "might be nothing, might be a value"; making it apply `print` (or any other `IO` action) if the value is there, and just do nothing if the value was `None`. Something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print `ioOption` optionMap (\a -> a + 1) (Some 5)
  print `ioOption` optionMap (\a -> a + 1) None
  print "done"
```

Where I've just swapped out the `$` operator, which was directly applying `print` to the result of `optionMap`, for some new `ioOption` that applies `print` to the result of `optionMap` *only if it is not `None`*. You'll have just as much trouble implementing that as you do implementing `optionMap`.

---

Now, I know you said that using discriminated unions just added too much complexity to your code for you to bother with for your present purposes (although you seem to be willing to put in far more effort to *avoid* Maybe than you are to put into *using* it). But for completeness, I am going to show how these problems are solved using discriminated unions, in all their horrible "complexity":

```
data Option a = Some a | None

optionMap :: (a -> b) -> Option a -> Option b
optionMap _ None = None
optionMap f (Some x) = Some (f x)

ioOption :: (a -> IO ()) -> Option a -> IO ()
ioOption _ None = pure ()
ioOption f (Some x) = f x


main :: IO ()
main = do
  print `ioOption` optionMap (\a -> a + 1) (Some 5)
  print `ioOption` optionMap (\a -> a + 1) None
  print "done"
```

And running this:

```
❯ runhaskell bar.hs
6
"done"
```

Things to note here:

1. The types are *much* simpler, and say exactly what they do; we still get the full power of Haskell's error checking (try changing `Some 5` to `Some True`)
2. The implementation of `optionMap` is much simpler than any of our attempts with `Typeable`; we just write a case for `None` and a case for `Some` and we're done, which is about the minimal number of moving parts it would be possible to use
3. That's just about the **only** possible implementation we can give for `optionMap`. Haskell is (almost) *forcing* us to write correct code. (The only other things we could do that would pass the typechecker are return `Nothing` even in the `Some` case, return bottom/`undefined`, return bottom/`undefined` inside the `Some` constructor, or start messing with unsafe functions; all of those are *obviously* incorrect, so it's not hard to avoid accidentally writing any of them)
4. No extensions needed
5. We don't have to explicitly type annotate our numbers; Haskell's normal defaulting mechanism just works for us again

Of course, everything above (other than `main`) is *already implemented for you*. So you don't even need to write `Option`, `optionMap`, or `ioOption`. `Option` is `Maybe`, of course, `optionMap` is `fmap`, and `ioOption` is `mapM_` from `Data.Foldable` (or `traverse_` - they're the same thing only `traverse_` has a more general type; they both exist for historical reasons). So we can just write:

```
import Data.Foldable

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print `mapM_` fmap (\a -> a + 1) (Just 5)
  print `mapM_` fmap (\a -> a + 1) Nothing
  print "done"
```

---

Basically, whatever complexity you think you're avoiding by avoiding `Maybe` (or other discriminated unions), I **guarantee** you the alternatives are more complicated. You *may* just be not seeing how you can use the interfaces of `Maybe` (and other types) to write simpler code, in which case I'd be happy to answer further questions here. If you really just don't like writing constructor tags **so much** that things along the lines of our attempts at `optionMap` here seem preferable (if they could work), then you're really not going to enjoy using Haskell; it *is* a fundamental part of the language.

---

For the sake of completeness, I did think of one way to get an `optionMap` that really accepts "a function and either a value that can be passed to the function or None". It's not pretty, but it does work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}

data None = None

type family OptionResult a b
  where OptionResult None _ = None
        OptionResult _ b = b

class OptionMap a b a'
  where optionMap :: (a -> b) -> a' -> OptionResult a' b

instance OptionMap a b None
  where optionMap _ _ = None

instance (OptionResult a b ~ b) => OptionMap a b a
  where optionMap f x = f x


class OptionTraverse a a'
  where optionTraverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f ())-> a' -> f ()

instance OptionTraverse a None
  where optionTraverse _ _ = pure ()

instance OptionTraverse a a
  where optionTraverse f x = f x


main :: IO ()
main = do
  (print :: Int -> IO ()) `optionTraverse` optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) (5 :: Int)
  (print :: Int -> IO ()) `optionTraverse` optionMap (\a -> a + (1 :: Int)) None
  print "done"
```

The problem with this approach is it *destroys* type inference. GHC needs to know the type of everything very precisely in order to resolve the instance and type family we're using. GHC won't use the input and output types of the various function's we're using to constrain each other's types because we don't directly connect them with each other; if their types were wrong we wouldn't get a type-mismatch error, we'd get an error about it being unable to resolve the type class. And thus any polymorphic thing (like `print`) *can't* have its type resolved by connecting with something else; we have to explicitly provide a type annotation.

So this approach is *not* something I recommend. Programming with it with any scale will be very difficult. I include it only to show you the lengths you have to go to get your idea of **how** this should be done to work in Haskell, as compared to the extremely simple example using `Maybe` that does **what** you want, just not **How** you wanted it to work. (I would argue that the "how" of the `Maybe` approach is also a *better* way for it to work, but that is subject to taste, so I won't say that is definitive; I think you will have to agree it is simpler and easier to use, however)

Comment: I do really appreciated your answer, Ben. Thanks a lot. I understand. In fact, my ultimate goal is to write a small library for me, and which has structure like `IO (M a)` which works fine so far,  and now if I employ `Maybe`, it becomes `IO (M (Maybe a))`. With this structure, the entire code becomes complicated by just using `Maybe` and for some point it seems impossible to process with the internal `Maybe a` especially with IO.

Comment: What I wished is avoiding `Maybe` to keep the current structure of `IO (M a)` even with `None` feature. I would chose the additional complexity resides within the local function instead of altering the basic structure with `Maybe` and spreading the entire code. That's my wish in principle, however reading your dedicated post, it seems impossible whatever we tried.

Comment: Surely, I presented a issue as a question a concise as possible, however the reality is more complicated. I do understand in this simple level, your presentation with normal `Maybe` approach is so much simpler than using `Typeable` hacking, and I do agree. However probably you agree with me we definitely have to write a complicated code mixed with `IO` and `maybe` monads, that is why we need `MaybeT` monad transformer, that I also wanted to avoid. It's not an easy problem as you say, at all.

Comment: It's so obvious you are the true expert of Haskell language, and reading your whole explanations, it's no doubt to use `Maybe` is inevitable approach, and I will give up for typeable-hack. Your statement makes sense.

Comment: @sailsky If you can show us more of the actual problem, I believe we would be able to help quite a bit more. If you could give us an example of the code becoming complicated because of `Maybe`, for instance

Comment: There are many things built into the standard Haskell library which makes things like this easier. One of those things might apply to the problems you are having.

Comment: The last thing I want to hold is, I still think this is due to limitation of Haskell/GHC type system capability. As I told you earlier, dependency type in such as Idris can achieve this without losing integrity. Probably requirement of so many language extension is due to the lack of dependency types.

Comment: @DavidYoung Thanks for your kind offer. Yes, if you say so, I should, Probably in new Question. Either way, I really would like to know how you guys as the true expert can deal with the complicated `Maybe` structure with `IO`.  I studied `MaybeT`, but I am not sure even with the monad-transformer, it would help for `IO (M (Maybe a))`.

Comment: Thanks again Ben and David. I will notice you if I did new Q.

Comment: @DavidYoung and Ben, I created another question for my concrete purpose, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275290/mapping-io-s-maybe-a-in-haskell Please review, thank you.