# mapping `IO (S (Maybe a))` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Based on [Data.Typeable cast and Maybe pattern match behavior in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273517/data-typeable-cast-and-maybe-pattern-match-behavior-in-haskell)

I have

- a structure: `data S a = S {val :: IO a}`
- a structure: `S (Maybe a))`
- a structure: `IO (S (Maybe a)))`
- a function : `Maybe a -> IO (S (Maybe a))`

then, basically need a function

`_map :: (Maybe a -> IO (S (Maybe a))) -> S (Maybe a) -> IO (S (Maybe b))`

The code is pretty simplified for this question, and there is a reason to have the structures and function like this for my purpose. For instance `S {val :: IO a}` actually hold a field value of `Data.Vector.Mutable` that is why the type is `IO a`.

The basic concept is simply map/function-application on the value.

In the case of `Maybe a` is `Nothing`, I want the code behaves nothing on `IO` and return `IO (S (Nothing))`.

```
data S a = S
  { val :: IO a
  }

_val :: S (Maybe a) -> IO (Maybe a)
_val = \sMaybeA -> val sMaybeA

_map :: (Maybe a -> IO (S (Maybe b))) -> S (Maybe a) -> IO (S (Maybe b))
_map = \f -> \sMaybeA -> do
  val <- sMaybeA |> _val
  sMaybeB <- val >>= f
             -- Expected type: IO (S (Maybe a))
             --   Actual type: Maybe (S (Maybe a))
  pure sMaybeB
  -- another obvious error because sMaybeB has the error
```

Of course, the error is obvious so I understand how this occurs, and that is not the scope of this quesion.

I simply can't figure out how to accomplish the expected type with the mixed structure of `IO` and `Maybe`. How can you fix this out?

Comment: While not impossible, an `IO a` in an `IO` (well here you basically have an `IO (IO (Maybe a))`, is quite uncommon, and often means something is not well designed, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not fully familiar with the mutable vector interface. But I think usually you need to be in IO to generate and access mutable things, but you don't store then in IO fields, rather the functions that return the outer structure are in IO. i.e. I would expect a function returning `IO (S (Vector a))`, not a function returning `S (IO (Vector a))` or `IO (S (IO (Vector a)))`. I think you're effectively storing a program that will produce your a, rather than storing a vector. Maybe someone who knows `Data.Vector.Mutable` can confirm?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That is always what I also doubt and consider, but the outer `IO` is rather for development for Monad structure, so it's fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ben Thanks again. Actually, the vector itself is `IO` type because it's mutable vector `Data.Vector.Mutable`, and the outer `IO` is required in any way as it will be implemented as Monad as the final form .

Comment: @sailsky You should almost certainly be passing around the value that the `IO` action produces (using `>>=` and `<-`), rather than the `IO` action itself. In that case, `S` would not have an `IO` in it at all. Without more detail about where the `S` is coming from, it is hard to give more specific advice though.

Comment: @sailsky I know the outer IO is going to be required anyway, it's the inner one I suspect you don't need.

Comment: Maybe you can provide still more detail of specifically what you're trying to do. I share the other's views here in that I'm pretty confident that it's very unlikely that you need this "extra layer" of `IO`. In fact, one way to look at part of the interface that `Monad` provides is that it allows you to both collapse "duplicated layers" like this *and* also to often avoid having duplicated layers in the first place.

Comment: @DavidYoung It's actually, `Data.Vector.Mutable` and the exact type is ` Mut.MVector (PrimState IO) a'` where `Mut` is the typeclass and `a'` is `Maybe a`

Comment: @Ben as replied above, it's  `Data.Vector.Mutable.MVector (PrimState IO) a'` and since this is Mutable, I think it's `IO`, but for some reason, it's inner structure anyway, and if the mutable structure wraps the `S`, I need to recreate `S` every time, so for efficiency, I Bellevue it''s proper to hold inner mutable fields than can simply contains `Just a` or `Nothing`. Thanks anyway,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve. The way you nest `IO` within another `IO` (aka `S`) is a bit strange.

Also, your type for `_map` only admits trivial inhabitants:

```
_map :: (Maybe a -> IO (S (Maybe a))) -> S (Maybe a) -> IO (S (Maybe b))
```

Note the `b` at the very end. There is no way to obtain such a `b` from the arguments, forcing the code to always use `Nothing :: Maybe b`, suitably wrapped. I guess this is not what you want to do.

I changed the `b` into an `a`. Then we can test the result of `sMaybeA` and act accordingly.

```
_map :: (Maybe a -> IO (S (Maybe a))) -> S (Maybe a) -> IO (S (Maybe a))
_map f sMaybeA = do
  v <- val sMaybeA
  case v of
     Nothing -> return (S (return Nothing))
     Just _  -> f v
```

Note that, while this compiles, it could be something different from what you actually need.

Comment: Thanks and very sorry it's type and the precise one is `(Maybe a -> IO (S (Maybe b))) -> S (Maybe a) -> IO (S (Maybe b))`, and I need to investigate more then will accept as the answer.

Comment: I sort of figure out every problem so far for some reason, asking this Question and reading your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like your concerns about Haskell's type system stem from the misleading API design you've showcased here. You're trying to nest your types rather than compose them. I believe that, while writing Haskell, you'll find that Haskell types compose very well with each other. You don't have to fallback to naive yet ugly nesting.

What about something like this instead?

```hs
newtype S a = S { val :: IO (Maybe a) }

instance Functor S where
  fmap f = S . fmap (fmap f) . val

instance Applicative S where
  pure = S . pure . pure
  S f <*> S v = S $ liftA2 (<*>) f v

instance Monad S where
  S ma >>= f = S $ do
    maybex <- ma
    case maybex of
      Nothing -> pure Nothing
      Just a -> val $ f a

weirdMap :: (a -> S b) -> S a -> S b
weirdMap f sa = do
  value <- sa
  f value
```

There's no nested `IO`, because you *never* need nested `IO` (unless you're working with `STM`). You can simply combine your `IO`s, doesn't matter if one of them is just for a mutable array.

I've also taken the liberty to embed the `Maybe a` within `S`, as it seems like that's what your API does anyway. However, you may very well take it out and still proceed with the `Functor`/`Applicative`/`Monad` instances, and continue to keep a flat `IO` hierarchy.